# lineWidth SwiftUI not proper

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm getting below output when I'm doing corner radius to `Rectangle` in swift UI.
[image]

```
   var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(Rectangle()
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 50))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
```

Top and bottom is correct but leading and trailing lineWidth is half of given value.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stroke is centred by line. As far as I understood your expectation it can be solved as

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .overlay(Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.white).padding(50))
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // comment if you don't need full screen
```